# LabVIEW in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, software-installation

I have a licensed copy of LabVIEW 2019 SP1. I also have NVIDIA Jetson DSBOARD-NX2 which supports only Ubuntu Linux 18.04. Shall I install LabVIEW 2019 SP1 on Ubuntu 18.04. I would like to know about the compatibility? It would be very helpful, if anyone can help.

Comment: What does Labview support say?

Comment: What is the question? You say that the software supports 18.04 and ask if you should install it to 18.04...